# TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer Deadlock

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I am having trouble with a large project involving mutlithreading, `TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer` and occasional deadlocks.
Is my understanding correct, that a deadlock can only occur if one thread does not release a lock (`EndRead` or `EndWrite`) and *another* thread wants to lock it?
I have packed all my `BeginRead`and `BeginWrite`with `try finally` and can't think of any reasoon why it should stall... :-(

Comment: Recommended: [The Deadlock Empire](https://deadlockempire.github.io).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have two or more `TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer`, you have to pay attention how you use those.

Imagine one thread has acquired the first lock and another thread acquired the second lock. If the threads each want to acquire the lock he doesn't have yet, then you have a deadlock!

Comment: But this could only happen if INSIDE a beginwrite/beginread I would ask for another locks beginwrite/beginread, right?

Comment: Is there a good way to debug this? I can't find the problem :-/

Comment: @WolfgangBures Maybe the good old message? Add OutputDebugString messages in the begin/end of all locks.